# Django - override model's default value in ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out how to override the (showing of the) default value that is provided on a model field. It seems using the 'placeholder' attribute does not work.

I have an optional field that I want to present in a form, but if a user does not enter something then the default value should be stored in the database.
However, I also don't want to present that default value to the user in the form.

Assume:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="some default value here")
```

and

```
class NewSomeModel(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['title']
        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "My placeholder text"})}
```

Upon rendering the form the text in the field always represents the model's default value, so "some default value here".
How can I get the actual placeholder attribute to work?

Comment: Just remove the `default`. If there is a default that is the `value=...`, and this takes presedence over `initial`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the `default=…` value in the model, since a value in a form takes presence over the placeholder. Furthermore a model should not be concerned about user interaction, or at least not to the extent that you define default values for this.

If that is really not an option, you can define an [**`initial=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#initial) in the form field:

```
class NewSomeModel(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        initial=None,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'My placeholder text'})
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['title']
```

You can specify a default value in case the value is missing by overriding the `clean_title` method in this case:

```
class NewSomeModel(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        initial=None,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'My placeholder text'})
    )

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        return title or 'some-default-value-here'
    
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['title']
```

Comment: Hoi Willem, that would work. But maybe let me to rephrase the question a little. So the use case would be , for example, a user being able to define a url (as text) to a profile picture, but if no input is provided , then I would fall back on some default value (or static img in this case). Am I going about that the wrong way then?

Comment: @RebelPoet: I think you caneither implement that in the render logic, so check if the field is `NULL`/empty string, and render a default one instead, or you can specify a value in the `clean_title` method in this case.